# GWT 2.4 SingleSelectionModel issue in IE

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT2.4 and I'm I applied singleselectionmodel to my DataGrid to enable capturing of table row selection.

```
final SingleSelectionModel<Map<String,String>> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Map<String,String>>();
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
```

While I'm hovering the mouse pointer over the contents of the DataGrid, I noticed it is slow and it take a few seconds to highlight the row where the mouse pointer is pointing. This issue only happens in IE11 but when I tried using Chrome, I don't see any lag.

Is there a workaround to this? Thanks.